# Remove hover tooltip from Google Visualization pie chart (core chart)

Tags: javascript, html, google-visualization

How to remove hover tooltip from Google Visualization pie chart (core chart)? Need to make it work cross-browser, eg, IE, FF, Chrome, Safari, Opera

[image]

Edit: I need the slices to be be clickable too.
`enableInteractivity : false` removes the hovers but doens't throw 'select' or other interaction-based events.

Comment: From this: http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=383 it doesn't seem that you can do it. Unless you can hack onmouseover somehow...

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes.html - "Tooltip - In the current version, tooltips open automatically on mouse hover; you cannot open or close them using the API." I checked source code for SVG and it doesn't seem that there's any class that that assigned to tooltips so hiding using css or js will not work.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Maybe you need to add this to your chart's options

```
'tooltip' : {
  trigger: 'none'
}
```

In this way you can leave enableInteractivity set to true.

Comment: that does not work for me. the tooltip boxes are still displayed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This attribute was released after I posted my question. It was a much needed functionality, hence Google took it up.

Comment: @Dominik: I had a similar issue with the Timeline visualization, as the `tooltip` option doesn't seem to be supported. I wasn't able to suppress the hover event itself, but defining a CSS style of `display: none;` for elements with the class `google-visualization-tooltip` kept the Timeline tooltips hidden. The class seems generic enough that I'd expect this might work with other chart types as well.

Comment: In the case of the wordTree visualization, @jmikola suggestion didn't work either. My dirty hack was to modify the id values of the elements I didn't want any event to be associated to.

Comment: Thanks - worked for me, only with no quotes around `tooltip` so in context it's `var options = { tooltip: { trigger: 'none' } };`

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 19):

Use the [enableInteractivity = False](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart.html) option.  It will disable interaction and hover.

```
chart.draw(data, {   
  width: 400, 
  height: 240, 
  title: 'Your chart and data',
  enableInteractivity: false,
  hAxis: {title: 'Year'}
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nix. However, I need the slices to be be clickable too.
"enableInteractivity : false" removes the hovers but doens't throw 'select' or other interaction-based events.

Comment: My God, 2 hours searching for this. Thanks Bro

Answer (score 3):

set tooltip: { isHtml: true } in option section.

```
chart.draw(data, {   
  tooltip: { isHtml: true },
  width: 400, 
  height: 240, 
  title: 'Title',
  hAxis: {title: 'Year'}
});
```

in css file

```
div.google-visualization-tooltip { display:none }
```

Answer (score 2):

This remove hover event but maintains the click event:

```
tooltip: { trigger: 'selection' }
```